# Monitor Folder Contents with launchd - Including Subfolders?

Tags: macos, script, launchd

I want to make a shell script that runs any time the contents of a particular folder on my server are changed. Seems easy enough at first, because `launchd` has a directive called `WatchPaths` which triggers your script any time the contents of a folder change.

HOWEVER `WatchPaths` is not triggered by changes in subfolders. The folder I'm trying to watch is a few hundred MB of small web files, nested several levels deep in sub folders. Far too many folders to try to manually list each one.

Is there some other **sane** way to accomplish this?

Comment: The problem is, the root folder hasn't changed, no matter what you do to sub folders.  What exactly are you attempting to do?  This sounds like a long way around to do something.

Comment: I want to have a folder that permanently lives on disk, and I want to copy it to a RAM disk every time something in the folder, anything in the folder, changes. I know I could do the whole thing by timer, or with a manual 'button'. But both of those solutions have drawbacks that `WatchPaths` would solve completely.... if it could see into subfolders too.

Comment: a bit similar question [Folder Action Script: Alert when a file is being moved or deleted in a folder and its subfolders](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373431/)

Answer (score 4):

`WatchPaths` doesn't appear to be able to watch a sub-directory recursively, so the best you can do with it is watch a single directory's activities. You might want to take a look at Folder Actions, they're discussed in detail in this blog post titled: [Setup OS X Folder Actions to Know When a File is Added](https://www.lifewire.com/use-os-x-folder-actions-to-know-2260158) as well.

Another alternative is to use a CLI tool that's available in Homebrew via the `brew install fswatch` command. `fswatch` is a cross platform implementation that works on most flavors of *NIX includes macOS.

> The FSEvents monitor, available only on OS X, has no known
>   limitations, and scales very well with the number of files being
>   observed.

#### Example

Here I've created a sub-directory called `~/somedir`. I then invoked `fswatch against  this directory:

```
$ mkdir ~/somedir
$ fswatch /some/dir
```

Now if we start adding files and sub-directories `fswatch` will notify:

```
$ touch ~/somedir/afile
fwatch msg>> /Users/joeuser/somedir/afile

$ mkdir ~/somedir/anotherdir
fswatch msg>> /Users/joeuser/somedir/anotherdir

$ touch ~/somedir/anotherdir/afile
fswatch msg>> /Users/joeuser/somedir/anotherdir/afile
```

The above can be adapted for use in a shell script which can take whatever other actions you require when any changes are detected against the directory tree that `fswatch` is monitoring.

#### Other Examples

To act on file system activity you can use one of these 2 patterns:

```
$ fswatch -0 path | while read -d "" event \
  do \
    // do something with ${event}
  done
```

Or this:

```
$ fswatch -o path | xargs -n1 -I{} program
```

#### References

- [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch)
- [Is there a command like “watch” or “inotifywait” on the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac)

Comment: Can you provide an example to run fswatch as daemon with Launchd ?

Comment: @KhurshidAlam - https://szymonkrajewski.pl/automatic-file-versioning-after-change-using-fswatch-and-git/.